# Adding tables via DAO to a database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

As a general question which would really help me "connect the dots" with my studies.
I am currently doing exercises working with DAO and Learning how to add tables automatically.  Although i have been working with databases for many years, i question, what type of scenerarios would it be vantagious to use this function.  When is it necessary to add tables to a database in an automatic way? Up until now, in all my experiences the tables i need have Always been defined from the beginning and I cant think of a situation where I could of benefited from using this function.  For example, i use frequently delete queries to help me clear tables and re-populate them, but when would it be necessary to actually "create" a new table"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have seen a scenario where new tables were created 'on the fly' (either via SQL create, or just DAO). With a shared database on a server, the application called for importing Excel data that a particular user was responsible for, so a table was created on the fly. Multiple users, changes in staff, need to keep data independent, etc. we could create their own table (name based on userid) that they had interfaces to do whatever they wanted with their own data. Not a typical scenario, but worked well for this application.